# me.libraryaddict.disguise does not exist but implemented with dependencies

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

So yeah title says it. I get the error: `me.libraryaddict.disguise does not exist` but I implemented it in the Dependencies in my Project Structure. I developed this plugin in IntelliJ and here's my code:

```java
import me.libraryaddict.disguise.DisguiseAPI;
import me.libraryaddict.disguise.disguisetypes.DisguiseType;
import me.libraryaddict.disguise.disguisetypes.MobDisguise;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
 
public class mobdisguise implements CommandExecutor {

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        Entity en = (Entity) sender;
        DisguiseAPI.disguiseToAll(en, new MobDisguise(DisguiseType.CREEPER));
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If class `me.libraryaddict.disguise`, is from library and that library is not provided at runtime (the library is not a plugin), then you must compile that library to your artifact.

If you are using *maven building system*, this can be done by adding it as your dependency and then using shading plugin to put it in the jar.

If you are using purely just *IntelliJ's building system*, you have to specify dependency scope, so that intelliJ knows that your plugin has to have this library in it's jar. More information on [official page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html).